# Printing my forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have an app that i want to show from my forms.py on my page (unidra.html). Actually I have my view:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import string, random
    from dracoin.apps.home.forms import GenEggForm

    def get_random_string(size):    
        chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

    def draegg_view(request):
        size = 40
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = GenEggForm(request.POST.get('random_string'))        
        else:
            form = get_random_string(size)
        return render_to_response('synopticup/unidra.html', {'random_string': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my forms.py:

```
class GenEggForm(forms.Form):
    Key = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and my unidra.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Contact us!! {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action='.' method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}           
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Generar</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that my page (unidra.html) don't print my form, I can't see my form. is possible that I do a bad declaration of my form.

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Comment: But you don't instantiate your form if it's not a POST, for song reason you call get_random_string instead

Comment: are you trying to initialize the form with the value returned from the `get_random_string` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
form = get_random_string(size)
```

Try

```
form = GenEggForm()
```

Thanks to karthikr, If you want to initialize the form, try this

```
form = GenEggForm(initial={'Key': get_random_string(size)})
```

And render this to template

No need to apologize, we all start learning from zero

Comment: If OP is trying to initialize, one slight modification should be `form = GenEggForm(initial={'Key': get_random_string(size)})`